# Magento 2 - Product Loses Thumbnail after quantity update

Tags: php, magento2

I'm not sure why everything is so difficult with Magento.  I am trying to update product quantities programatically.

```
try{
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $product->setStockData( [
        'qty' => $quantity
    ] );

    $this->productRepository->save($product);

} catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) { }
```

This seems to work just fine, however, when I go into the admin and look at the products list, the thumbnails are missing for any product that has been updated.

If I go into that product and look at its images they are all there and the thumbnail image still has the label/role "thumbnail" attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is by using the `StockRegistryInterface`

```
/**
 * @var StockRegistryInterface
 */
protected $stockRegistry;

/**
 * Inventory constructor.
 * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 */
public function __construct(
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
```

With the above code, you can use the following:

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

This code will not call unrelated observers or plugins that you may have on your project and it will not break the thumbnail